# change text-color of label on focus input

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<label>
    <p>text description</p>
    <input type="text">
</label>
```

When focus on `<input>`, I want to change the `text-color` inside the `<p>` tag.

How to write the CSS code?

Comment: Do you want to use Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the `:focus-within` pseudo-class selector.

> The :focus-within CSS pseudo-class matches any element that the :focus pseudo-class matches or that has a descendant that the :focus pseudo-class matches. (This includes descendants in shadow trees.)
>
> [**:focus-within @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

[Support Details](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within)

```css
lable {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

label:focus-within p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <p>text description</p>
    <input type="text">
</label>
```

Comment: can you check color for p tag is not changing

Comment: It does in Chrome 60 & FF

Answer (score 6):

You can't access the previous sibling element (`<p>`) from `<input>`.

But you can use the following solution:

```css
label {
  display:flex;
}
p {
  order:-1;
}
input:focus ~ p {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="text">
  <p>text description</p>  
</label>
```